# SQL Server 2008R2: Show top 1000 records in DESCENDING order

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there an option to set for SQLServer 2008R2 that all tables which I open Show the top 1000 records in descending order not in ascending order?
Normally I Need to see the latest records.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: Writing a simple `SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY <<primary_key_column>> DESC` is too much?

Comment: Your question is based on an incorrect premise -- Management Studio doesn't show the rows in *any* order, because it just uses `SELECT TOP(1000)`. SQL Server returns the rows in any order it wants, which just usually happens to be the order in which the rows were inserted. If you want to order by something specific (like the primary key), you'll have to write the query yourself -- in general there's no way of knowing what order is "appropriate".

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, `ORDER BY` is not honored in views.  The only way to guarantee ordering of results is with `ORDER BY` in the outer `SELECT` query.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Not really, if the table has an index then the rows will be returned ordered by the PK. Otherwise, the order in which the rows are returned can't be guaranteed without an `ORDER BY`. Rows returned are not in the order in which they were inserted but in the order in which they can be read fastest from disk.

Comment: @DanGuzman Oh, you're right Dan. I remember now I had problems with this in views.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, indexing does not guarantee ordering of results.  `ORDER BY` is required even though the results may be returned in desired order by happenstance without it.  SQL Server can return rows it any order it chooses if not otherwise constrained.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu The order in which rows are returned is *never* guaranteed if you don't specify `ORDER BY`, index or not. That all implementations of SQL Server happen to generate a trivial sequential plan that involves scanning the clustered index in order is nice for a trivia quiz, but not something you want to rely on in a production system.

Comment: Michael, There is no option in SQLServer2008R2 to set an order by (asc or desc). You can go to Tools >> Options to set the number of rows to be returned by default, but you cannot set the order by clause. And yes, as others have pointed out, do not assume that the rows returned are in any particular order.

Comment: Thanks to all. I wanted to save myself the 'order by' whenever I open a table. I was looking for a descending Option for the 'is identity' field...Michael

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu The only way to get data in correct order is to use `ORDER BY`. Period. Clustered key guarantee nothing: **[No Seatbelt - Expecting Order without ORDER BY](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx)**. Check simple demo from link

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ok, then I've been told wrongly. This has been a **good lesson**.

Comment: You can use other interface, like Access and linked tables.